# Node/Express, Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have two routes, '/all' and 'question/all' that with my knowledge should do the same thing. The problem is one works the other one doesn't.

The index-routes(/all) works and most of it has Express generated for me but question-routes I've done from scratch.

All routes in /question works except /question/all. What could I possibly forgot?

This is the Error i get:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.contentType.res.type (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:537:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:129:14)
    at fn (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:934:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:353:10)
    at View.render (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:566:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
    at module.exports (/Users/rick/projects/express-test/app.js:70:7)
```

This is my questions-routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Question = require('../models/question');

// Route: '/questions'
router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) {
    var newQuestion = new Question();
    newQuestion.text = req.body.question;

    newQuestion.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({
            message: 'new question was created',
            question: newQuestion
         });
    });
});

router.get('/:question_id',function(req, res) {
    Question.findById(req.params.question_id, function(err, question) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(question);
    });
});

router.get('/all',function(req, res) {
    Question.find(function(err, allQuestions) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(allQuestions);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my index-routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Question = require('../models/question');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/all',function(req, res) {
    Question.find(function(err, allQuestions) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(allQuestions);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that headers are at the *beginning* of any HTTP request - when you do `res.send() ` the headers are sent and the function does not end, and it tries to do `res.json()`, which will try to set headers for content type, but it cannot, because the response has already started. Try `return res.send(err);` when you do that to avoid this problem.

Comment: return res.send(err); didn't work. :(

Comment: You are running both of these snippets together? If so then you are registering two functions with the same route, and both of them are trying to  do `res.json` which will cause the same problem (I'm a little less certain here because I don't frequently register the same route twice)

Comment: No I use route '/all' for one of them and '/questions/all' for the other one. They are in different files as well. index.js and questions.js

Comment: I newbie when it comes to node/express. This is the first project.. Expect me to forgot/missed some important stuff.. :p

Comment: It works now. I moved get '/all' function to the top, above POST '/new' I have no idea why that worked though.. :O